# Flutter web debug is working but build web shows a blank page

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web, dart2js, dart-dev-compiler

`flutter doctor` result

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.21.0-1.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

I was working with flutter v 1.20-7.2.pre in beta channel and encountered this problem. So I switched to dev channel.

I tried running the example project (boilerplate) as well and got a blank page. The console shows some errors in main.dart.js and js_helper.dart shows the error:

```
Could not load content for org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/js_helper.dart (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)
```

### To Reproduce the problem

Create the sample project in any IDE
Run the following commands:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

OR

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

Then, run:
`flutter build web`

After this, I used python to run localhost:
`python -m http.server 8080` in the $root_folder\build\web

I found another answer which suggested hosting the build\web folder as localhost has CORS problems

Also, I tried using the debug mode: `flutter run -d Chrome` and it worked!

**Extra information:** I am testing this on Chrome v 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answers to this question here. It was actually happening due to firebase and was not a flutter issue at all.

- [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2826)
- [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62547724/11626847)

Answer (score 1):

Must run a server.

```
dart pub global activate dhttpd

dart pub global run dhttpd --path build/web/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the below line from the index.html

`<base href="/">`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
flutter build web --base-href=/build/web/
```

so that the base href matches with the directory structure of your dev machine.

Do not forge you need to rebuild it

```
flutter build web
```

when you deploy it to the hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

Can't run when building web

to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cess to internal resource at 'file:///F:/user/Flutter%20Projects/web-app/web/manifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.