# Flutter web project don't work on hosting

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

During coding ( flutter web ) on computer, all work fine, I run website on google in debugging, and there not any problem, when I make `flutter build web --release`, and upload files to 000webhost, there nothing.. `only white screen.`

Comment: And? Are there errors on your server or in your browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63057889/11626847)

It usually happens because of improper placement of firebase JS SDK scripts. You have to setup the SDK before the script tag with main.dart.js.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `<base href="/">` tag in web/index.html to the path where your app is hosted. For example, to host your Flutter app at myapp.dev/flutter_app, change this tag to `<base href="/flutter_app/">`.

or you can even delete this line and it will work.

reference : [Hosting a Flutter app at a non-root location](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies)